# Como implementar tubos y filtros en Java

Tags: java

Es que necesito implementar "tubos y filtros" en una aplicacion, entonces tengo una aplicación que recibe una pregunta de un usuario y le contesta si la pregunta esta registrada en la base de datos, entonces por ejemplo si el usuario pregunta "¿que día es hoy?" el programa busca en la base de datos si la pregunta existe y le contesta que día es, pero entonces lo interesante es que digamos si el usuario ingresa "¿cual día es hoy?" el programa debería ser capaz de responderle, osea como analizar el String que el usuario ingresa y compararlo con el que esta guardado en base de datos y si son parecidos ser capaz de contestarle que día es, y así con varias preguntas que ya estén guardadas en base de datos, que aunque el usuario no ingrese exactamente el String que esta guardado en la base de datos, el programa identifique si pregunta algo parecido.

Alguien tiene idea como hacer eso?

Ahora mismo solamente cargo las preguntas y respuestas de mi base de datos, valido si el String que el usuario digito es igual al de alguna de las preguntas que tengo guardadas y de acuerdo a eso doy una respuesta

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FormularioPreguntasVista extends Observable {
    private InputText txtPregunta;
    private InputTextarea txtRespuesta;
    private InputText txtContadorRespuestas;
    private InputText txtContadorRespuestasNo;
    private List<Preguntas> preguntas;
    private List<Respuestas> respuestas;
    private static Integer contadorRespuestas=0;
    private static Integer contadorRespuestasNo=0;


    private CommandButton botonPreguntar;
    @PostConstruct
    public void resetearContadores() {
        contadorRespuestas=0;
        contadorRespuestasNo=0;
    }
     @ManagedProperty(value = "#{BusinessDelegatorView}")
     private IBusinessDelegatorView businessDelegatorView;
     // Cargo las preguntas que estan en la base de datos
    public List<Preguntas> getPreguntas() {
        if(preguntas==null) {
            preguntas = businessDelegatorView.consultarTodasPreguntasBusiness();
        }
        return preguntas;
    }

    public void setPreguntas(List<Preguntas> preguntas) {
        this.preguntas = preguntas;
    }
    // Cargo las respuestas que estan en la base de datos
    public List<Respuestas> getRespuestas() {
        if(respuestas==null) {
            respuestas = businessDelegatorView.consultarTodasRespuestasBusiness();
        }
        return respuestas;
    }

    public void setRespuestas(List<Respuestas> respuestas) {
        this.respuestas = respuestas;
    }
    public String preguntarAction() {

        try {
            getPreguntas();
            getRespuestas();
            for (int i = 0; i < preguntas.size(); i++) {
                // Valido si coincide el String que el usuario ingreso al que esta en base de datos para cada pregunta
                if(txtPregunta.getValue().toString().toLowerCase().equals(preguntas.get(i).getPregunta().toLowerCase())) {
                    Long idPregunta=preguntas.get(i).getIdPregunta();
                    if(idPregunta==1) {
                        Date ahora = new Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy", new Locale("es", "ES"));
                        String fecha = simpleDateformat.format(ahora);
                        txtRespuesta.setValue(fecha);
                        contadorRespuestas+=1;
                        txtContadorRespuestas.setValue(contadorRespuestas);                     
                    }else if(idPregunta==3) {
                        Date ahora = new Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy", new Locale("es", "ES"));
                        String fecha = simpleDateformat.format(ahora);
                        txtRespuesta.setValue(""+ahora.getHours()+":"+ahora.getMinutes()+":"+ahora.getSeconds());
                        contadorRespuestas+=1;
                        txtContadorRespuestas.setValue(contadorRespuestas);
                    }else {
                        txtRespuesta.setValue(respuestas.get(i).getRespuesta());    
                        contadorRespuestas+=1;
                        txtContadorRespuestas.setValue(contadorRespuestas);

                        }
                    break;
                }else if(!txtPregunta.getValue().toString().contains("¿") || !txtPregunta.getValue().toString().contains("?")){
                    FacesMessage mensaje=new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Tu pregunta no contiene signos de interrogacion (¿?), porfavor incluyelos", "");
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("", mensaje);
                    break;
                }else if(i==preguntas.size()-1 && !txtPregunta.getValue().toString().toLowerCase().equals(preguntas.get(i).getPregunta().toLowerCase())){
                    txtRespuesta.setValue("No tengo respuesta para eso");
                    contadorRespuestasNo+=1;
                    txtContadorRespuestasNo.setValue(contadorRespuestasNo);
                }
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesMessage mensaje=new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), "");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("", mensaje);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega lo que llevas hecho y donde tienes dudas, de paso lee [ask]

Comment: @Aprendiz, listo amigo si tienes idea como se puede lograr lo que menciono en el enunciado te lo agradezco :) quedo atento a cualquier inquitetud